# Why Math Object does not need new keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I have know that `Math` is an Object in javascript, however in the book it says when use the Math Object, we do not need to use the new keyword.For example,

```
var pi = Math.PI;
alert(pi);
```

I want to know why it does not need, and in other Object, like `Date`, it needs the new keyword.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/413898/2357233

Answer (score 4):

`Math` is actually the name of a property of the implicit `global` object in ECMAScript, which is a plain-old Javascript object, of type `Math` (defined by giving it properties to this single instance, similar to how JSON works). This is documented here in the specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8

The `Math` object can be thought of like this:

```
// within the "global" context:
var Math = {
    PI: 3.14,
    sin: function(x) { ... },
    cos: function(x) { ... }
};
```

Note that no constructor function is defined (nor is `Call` defined either), so the expression `new Math()` is meaningless and undefined. If it was, then it would look like this:

```
function Math() {
    this.PI = 3.14;
    this.sin = function(x) { ... };
    this.cos = function(x) { ... };
};
var Math = new Math();
```

Comment: I will also add that having a `Math` constructor that creates many instances wouldn't make sense because constructors are useful when we want each instance to have its own state; like each **Person** having a unique name and address. Mathematical expressions have a specific definition (_you can't change the value of PI_) and you can't change their definitions. That's why I think the `Math` object is implemented as a singleton. Basically **Math** is _Math_ so having many **Math**s is the same thing, therefore why not have just one.

Answer (score 4):

```
typeof Math -->    "object"
typeof Date -->    "function"
```

Math is an Object and Date is constructor function.

`new` key word is used to initialize an instance with a constructor function not with objects.

Answer (score 1):

The new keyword is used when you are dealing with constructor functions.
Math is a global object that has already been instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a `new Date([optional parameter])` you create a new instance of the `Date` function which stores data specific to this instance (date and time). `Math` does not need to store any instance specific data, because `PI`does not change and all `Math` functions, like `sin`, `cos`, `max` etc., they always do the same thing. That's why `Math` exists as a static object (like a static class in other languages). There is no need to create new instances of this object, you can use the same instance everywhere. BTW `Date` has static methods too, like `Date.parse()`. You dont need to create a new `Date` to use this method. You call it like you would call `Math.cos(x)`, just `Date.parse('2014-11-04')`.